# Is there a way to know expire vault client tokens?

Tags: java, hashicorp-vault

I'm using https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle.html to generate vault client tokens,but I want to know tokens expire state. Is that possible ?

Comment: Do you receive lease_duration field in response?

Comment: no, i can get lease_duration is constant. i need to know token is expired or not expired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get **lease_duration** and compare it with the current date time.
If current date time is after **lease_duration**, token should be expired.
Can you please try?

Comment: I can do that. It will be work but i just wondering is it provided by hashicrop-vault?

Comment: I think yes it should be provided by HashiCorp.
The response should contain the following value: auth.lease_duration

Comment: @myratas have you fixed your problem?

Comment: i am still searching on [vault-java-driver](https://github.com/BetterCloud/vault-java-driver) if i cant find it i will use lease duration and compare

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty straight forward if you have the token itself, as there are multiple ways to check validity:

```
vault token lookup
```

or with a cURL request + jq:

```
curl -H "X-Vault-Request: true" -H "X-Vault-Token: $(vault print token)" https://{{ your-vault-server-here }}/v1/auth/token/lookup-self | jq -re .data.ttl
```

The first command will fail with a 403 error (and return a non-zero code) if the token is expired, or print out a nicely formatted overview of the token's details (and return zero) if the token is still valid.

The second command does exactly the same with the difference that it prints out the `ttl` in seconds if the token is valid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try these commands on my project